# Displaying DigestEncodeFunction Error in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

When I am trying to execute my created script on another system then it's throwing this error like "Displaying DigestEncodeFunction Error in JMeter". PFA Screenshot for the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2woq.jpg)

Comment: Try `SHA-256` instead

Answer (score 0):

1. Please don't post [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) in form of a [screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2897748)
2. You forgot to include your [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) call itself

The first problem is that you're using wrong algorithm name, it should be `SHA-256`, for possible algorithms check out [`Algorithms` section of MessageDigest class JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest)

Just in case here how it looks now for [Java 8](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/):

[image]

If you have troubles when it comes to coming up with proper JMeter Function syntax - go for the [Functions Helper Dialog](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#function_helper)

[image]

[image]

Here is the function which generates SHA-256 hash of string `foo` using `bar` as the salt:

```
${__digest(SHA-256,foo,bar,,)}
```

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)